# How does bash history work with iterm2?

Tags: bash, iterm2

I'm very confused by bash history with iterm2. For example, if I have a terminal window open and then hit command-n, I get a new terminal with a prepopulated bash history of 500 commands. None of these commands come from the terminal I had previously opened. My .bash_profile file does not contain any commands that modify the history.

Can someone please spell out for me where iterm2 is getting its bash history from and why it's different for different terminals?

Comment: Use the control keys to move through your history, CTRL-n and CTRL-p.

Comment: I think Cmd-N just opens a new terminal window; the previous session hasn't written its history to `~/.bash_history` yet, it's just in-memory, and you seem to have a history size of 500.

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux and its applications. [su] or [unix.se] would be better places for questions like this.